# AngularJS scope is not available when using Bootstrap Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to use this plugin with angularjs to validate forms http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/ plugimg

I've tried a lot but I don't know why the scope variable is not accessible inside the plugins submit method. Hope someone could help me!

Here's the Controller

```
 app.controller('LoginController', function($scope,$http,$localStorage) {

      //initialize plugin on controller load
      $('#loginform').validator();

      //gets called on form submit
      $('#loginform').validator().on('submit', function (e) {

        //below line says : if there are no errors then coninue
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            $http.post('api/user/login',{
                email: $scope.email, // is undefine
                password: $scope.password // is undefined
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                $localStorage.isLoggedIn = 1;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        }

        //prevent form submit
        return false;

      });

  });
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="LoginController">

  <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate id="loginform">

    <div class="form-group">

      <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail ID</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email" required> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-model="password" required>

      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-in"></i> Login
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>

  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: its not advisable to write jquery code inside angular code; angular code uses its own angular-context; so u will always be worried as to which context ur code is in. i would recommend u to use only ng + bootstrap . All validations that u can do using jquery can be done in angular too. Plus u remain in the angular context all time.

Comment: also see the angular package ng-messages, it will do u the job of display validation msgs. remember angular is a framework and its always good to go with the framework thingies that work with that framework.

Comment: Is there anyway we could make this code work without removing the jquery plugin?

Comment: y do u want to do it the wrong way? its a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

When the submit event is triggered the values of `$scope.email` and `$scope.password` will be undefined because you have created an event which is executed outside of angulars controll (outside of the digest loop which makes the dirty checking possible).

The solution is to remove the jQuery code and only use angular code.

Comment: @JSnow Yes, you can use the NgForm instead which has great features to validate forms using angularjs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm